# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'dim', when feeding input to Pytorch LSTM network

Tags: python, tuples, lstm, pytorch, torch

I am trying to run the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class LSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_shape, n_actions):
        super(LSTM, self).__init__()

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_shape, 12)
        self.hidden2tag = nn.Linear(12, n_actions)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.lstm(x)
        out = self.hidden2tag(out)
        return out


state = [(1,2,3,4,5),(2,3,4,5,6),(3,4,5,6,7),(4,5,6,7,8),(5,6,7,8,9),(6,7,8,9,0)]

device = torch.device("cuda")
net = LSTM(5, 3).to(device)

state_v = torch.FloatTensor(state).to(device)

q_vals_v = net(state_v.view(1, state_v.shape[0], state_v.shape[1]))
_, action = int(torch.max(q_vals_v, dim=1).item())
```

And that returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dikkerj/Documents/PycharmProjects/LSTMReactor/QuestionStackoverflow.py", line 26, in <module>
    q_vals_v = net(state_v.view(1, state_v.shape[0], state_v.shape[1]))
  File "/home/dikkerj/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 477, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dikkerj/Documents/PycharmProjects/LSTMReactor/QuestionStackoverflow.py", line 15, in forward
    out = self.hidden2tag(out)
  File "/home/dikkerj/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 477, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dikkerj/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 55, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "/home/dikkerj/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1022, in linear
    if input.dim() == 2 and bias is not None:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'dim'
```

Anyone knows how to fix this? (to get rid of the tensor being a tuple so that it can be fed into the LSTM network)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pytorch LSTM returns a tuple.
 So you get this error as your linear layer `self.hidden2tag` can not handle this tuple.

So change:

```
out = self.lstm(x)
```

to

```
out, states = self.lstm(x)
```

This will fix your error, by splitting up the tuple so that `out` is just your output tensor.

`out` then stores the hidden states, while `states` is another tuple that contains the last hidden and cell state.

*You can also take a look here:

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.LSTM*

*You will get another error for the last line as `max()` returns a tuple as well. But this should be easy to fix and is yet different error :)*

Answer (score 0):

Transform your state in a numpy array first:

```
state = np.array(state)
```

PyTorch is probably missing a `np.asarray` in their API.