# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'dim'

Tags: python, pytorch, time-series, transformer-model

> I am trying to build a transformer network by **PyTorch library**. The data set that I use is historical financial market data.

```
 x_train= torch.from_numpy(x_train_tfr)
 x_test= torch.from_numpy(x_test_tfr)
 y_train_tfr = torch.from_numpy(y_train_tfr)
 y_test_tfr = torch.from_numpy(y_test_tfr)
```

After data preparation, I use the below code to split x_train and y-train into 12 chunks:

```
x_train_split=torch.split(x_train_tfr,12, dim=0)
y_train_split=torch.split(y_train_tfr,12, dim=0)
```

> and then I use the below code to train my model:

```
transformer_model = nn.Transformer(nhead=16, num_encoder_layers=12)
src = x_train_split
tgt = y_train_split
out, state = transformer_model(src, tgt)
```

> but the result is as below :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-769f9734fa98> in <module>()
  3 src = x_train_split
  4 tgt = y_train_split
  ----> 5 out, state = transformer_model(src, tgt)

           1 frames
 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/transformer.py in forward(self, src,tgt, src_mask, tgt_mask, memory_mask, src_key_padding_mask, tgt_key_padding_mask,memory_key_padding_mask)
   134         """
   135 
   --> 136         is_batched = src.dim() == 3
   137         if not self.batch_first and src.size(1) != tgt.size(1) and is_batched:
   138             raise RuntimeError("the batch number of src and tgt must be equal")

  AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'dim'
```

> How could I solve this error? Do I have to do anything extra before my model trainin?

Comment: Check if it helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53032586/attributeerror-tuple-object-has-no-attribute-dim-when-feeding-input-to-pyt

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be to include the code that defines `x_train_tfr` and `y_train_tfr`. Clearly a single example from `x_train_tfr` is not a tensor as you expect it to be but is instead a tuple. Likely, the dataset implementation returns both the data itself (tensor) as well as some other information (ie metadata) that may be useful for some tasks, and these are returned as a tuple.

If this is the case you could get around this error easily by doing:

```
src = x_train_split[0]    # or whichever element of the tuple the data tensor is  
tgt = y_train_split 

# Note that model will expect a batch dimension so you'll need to 
# add a batch dimension even if you only have one data example per batch
out, state = transformer_model(src.unsqueeze(0), tgt.unsqueeze(0))
```

Comment: >  I edit my code and use DataLoader for batching the dataset before my model defining. Then I define transformer model with the change you mentioned , but I got the below error :''tuple' object has no attribute 'unsqueeze' '

Comment: Ok, in order for someone to help you with this you need to provide enough information that a poster can tell what `x_train_split` and `y_train_split` are. In other words, what are their data types? If they are tuples, what are the types and shapes of each element? etc.

Comment: Thanks for your guide, I will edit my question.